# Where are the Keyboard Settings Stored in MATE DE

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, keyboard-layout, mate, 18.10

I'm currently setting up a couple of computers with Ubuntu MATE 16.04. The default installation sets the Keyboard Layout to 'English', however, I need a 'German' keyboard layout. I figured out how to remove all Layouts and add 'German' as default keyboard layout in the GUI.

```
System -> Preferences -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Layouts
```

However, I have to setup around 20 computers and it would be neat if I could script those settings. So my questions is where are the keyboard settings stored such that I could copy it from one computer to all the others.

Answer (score 2):

## 1. MATE Desktop Environment session

### 1.1. Using `gsettings`

You need the following GSettings keys. Below is my example with two layouts (`us` and `ru`) using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> as layout switcher and ScrollLock LED as indicator of the second layout:

```
gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.kbd layouts "['us', 'ru']"
gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.kbd model "''"
gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.kbd options \
"['grp_led\tgrp_led:scroll', 'grp\tgrp:ctrl_shift_toggle']"
```

*Edit it for your case.*

### 1.2. Using `dconf`

Alternative method is to use `dconf` command:

```
cat <<EOF | dconf load /org/mate/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/
[kbd]
layouts=['us', 'ru']
model=''
options=['grp_led\tgrp_led:scroll', 'grp\tgrp:ctrl_shift_toggle']
EOF
```

*Edit it for your case.*

## 2. Terminal session and some GUI cases

Do not forget to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` to reconfigure keyboard layouts for terminal and some GUI sessions.
It will save its settings in `/etc/default/keyboard`.
You can configure it once, then copy this file to other machines. After changing this file you should update initramfs images with `sudo update-initramfs -k all -u`.

---

Also note, that MATE *Keyboard Preferences* may be opened with `mate-keyboard-properties`.

Comment: Do you know why it's `org/mate/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/kbd` in dconf dump but `org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.kbd` in gsettings ?

Comment: @expert this is because of their coexistence as described in [`org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.gschema.xml`](https://sources.debian.org/src/libmatekbd/1.16.0-2/libmatekbd/org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.gschema.xml.in/). You can find this file on installed system here - */usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.gschema.xml*.