# 16.04 MATE How to add Greek keyboard layout support

Tags: 16.04, keyboard-layout, language-support, ubuntu-mate

I am using Ubuntu MATE 16.04 and I am trying to add multi-language support. More specifically, add Greek keyboard input support along English.

For some reason I cannot properly add Greek keyboard support on my system.

1) I have tried adding it using the GUI tools but for some reason it could not display the keyboard layouts. I have some trouble including a screenshot but image if 2 options were present, *Country* and *Variants* but the buttons next to the didn't show any option.

Any way I think I manages to actually add Greek keyboard by the configuration files using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1061389/546065) (I used the one with the `gsettings`):

```
$gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.kbd layouts "['us', 'gr']"
$gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.kbd model "''"
$gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.kbd options \
"['grp_led\tgrp_led:scroll', 'grp\tgrp:alt_shift_toggle']"
```

I also changed the key combination for the language toggle.

The actual result is that I can see a second language in the keyboard preferences->layout.

The problem is that a) the keyboard shortcut does not work and b) even if I try to select the Greek layout I cannot. Right-click->Layouts-> There are 2 options but are not shown (like empty options).

2) I have tried to follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1144490/546065) which uses iBus. I followed the steps and now I have 2 language layouts (English, Greek) which I can choose but no actual difference is shown in the layout (both just write English).

I have included  in the *Next Input Method* but this does not seem to work either. So, I can choose it via the mouse but not with the keyboard shortcuts.

One difference is that in my case in the *Input Method* tab the *Preferences* button is disabled in both languages and I cannot choose it.

So, I guess I have too not working methods to input Greek. Probably, I should only keep one I guess but I haven't managed to make it work for either of them.

What should I do from here? How, should I proceed? Any ideas?

Comment: As per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOL#Ubuntu_16.04_Xenial_Xerus the MATE release has reached its End of Life. We can assist with upgrading you to 19.10 or 18.04 but MATE 16.04 is off-topic here.

Comment: @K7AAY I think you are being too strict here. You could just ignore the question or post a comment but since the probability of the working solution in 18.04 of also being useful in 16.04 is high enough this is a legitimate question in my opinion.

Comment: That was set in place long before I arrived here, and you will notice I am not the only person finding it relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to disable IBus and use XKB instead.

On clean fresh Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS VM the reproducible way to add Greek is the following - we change the `/etc/default/keyboard` to the following contents:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us,gr"
XKBVARIANT=","
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
```

then update initramfs for all kernels by `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` and reboot.

---

For your pre-configured system we can do the following:

1. Disable IBus by visiting `gnome-language-selector` and setting *Keyboard Input Method* to *None*
2. Reset MATE keyboard preferences with

   ```
   gsettings reset-recursively org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.kbd
   ```
3. Add Greek keyboard layout again

   ```
   gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.kbd model "'pc105'"
   gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.kbd layouts "['us', 'gr']"
   gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.kbd options "['grp\tgrp:alt_shift_toggle', 'grp_led\tgrp_led:scroll']"
   ```

Hope this helps.